# Why does get_name_by_addr return '' and org_by_addr return None?

Tags: python, geoip, maxmind

I am currently testing one of my classes which sets variables with the help of pygeoip.

`org_by_addr` returns `None` when there is nothing found in the database:

```
seek_org = self._seek_country(ipnum)
if seek_org == self._databaseSegments:
    return None
```

While the `country_name_by_addr` function returns an empty string.

This forces me to check if the return is `None` and then setting it to `''` to have the variables uniformly.

Does anybody know, what the reason is to give different returns when there is no entry in the database?

Comment: Hi PhillipB, I'd suggest using our [newer GeoIP2 databases](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/downloadable/) and [the corresponding python library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geoip2). This new code is *much* higher quality than the legacy libraries.

Comment: @DaveRolsky thanks a lot. I will have a look at it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the obvious "variable uniformity", what is the point of changing the NoneType to an empty string? There is a reason why

```
bool ('') == bool (None) == False
```

In my opinion this is a stylistic difference. However, when a package has different return types like this, it can hint several things:

-if the function returns None, you can probably guess that the function would return an instanced object if a match was found in the database.
-if instead of returning None, the function returns an empty string, you can at least expect the output of that function to return a valid string when an entry is found in the database.
-if the function returns 0 instead of None, you can probably guess that the function would return a number of some sort if an entry was found in the database

So really it's mostly about informing the user in some way about what a valid return type would be.

My final suggestion would be to do away with the traditional thought of "types" when using Python. By that I mean the C philosophy of typing. In python there is a reason that you can say:

```
if result:
    #some code
```

And have it be valid across several different "types".

Comment: I change it because i later do insert the variable in a database, which obviously doesnt work with a None. I've just been wondering why the returns are different, but the reason for not returning a valid value was the same (IP not in database).

Comment: I see, I misread your question as: "why would a function in ANY library not return a consistent type?" My mistake. It seems as though Mr. Rolsky provided some additional information, and that GeoIP2 is the library to use.